# how to fix this Error in Assembly command Prompt

Tags: assembly, cmd

**I've write this code and Debug it in CMD Assembly, Windows 7 X86 bit:**

```
rax = 53
rbx = 9
rcx = (PROT NUMBER)
n p.com (Write p.com)
w (Execute and write .com save it on my path)
q (quit)
```

*but when I RUN p.com this Error message show's up:*

> Program too big to fit in memory

[image: screenshot]

Comment: .com is a 16-bit DOS executable. You should not use 64-bit registers. Stick with ax/bx/cx

Comment: but please how can i write same code in x86 bit?

Comment: On your screenshot the program is 90kbytes. .COM cannot be more than 64kbytes. try to compile your code as .EXE. Maybe you could share the source anywhere?

Comment: @AlexanderZhak: `r..` are special commands of DEBUG.EXE. `rax` means: "show and edit register `AX`. DEBUG.EXE can not "compile" an .EXE.

Comment: http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug-manual.html

Comment: I wanna to show Check Port number like 443 and whatever, my Code it's not work on x86 bit.
@AlexanderZhak why run or Print 'Hello World' and why don't run my Code?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign are you referring to TCP ports?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yes my bro you can see in here:
http://www.menuetos.net/stack.txt

Answer (score 0):

The "w" command of debug need an address parameter example: "w cs:0100".